# How to thread-safely manipulate lists in Java?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a simple class with a linked list:

```
private final LinkedList<Object> list;
```

If I have two methods manipulating this list:

```
public void m1(){ ... list.poll()...}

public void m2(){...list.clear)....}
```

How do I make sure of ThreadSafety? Is it enough to have both methods receive the "synchronized" keyword, or am I required to put a

```
synchronized(list){
    System.out.println("locking on :"  + lock);
}
```

around the method-code?

Common sense tells me it is the second, but I would like confirmation, OR an easier way to make sure my list does not get messed up.

PS: Or would this be better placed in CodeReview? It feels more in place here, somehow.

Comment: I would suggest using `Synchronized` only around critical sections like `poll` and `clear` and not on the entire method.

Comment: Also, what about methods like `add()` and `remove()`?. You will have to *synchronize* on them too?

Comment: Ok, first of all: Thanks, all the answers have been helpful :). Due to circumstances of "there is an existing system around this", I ended up synchronizing the block that mattered. For almost all other cases, I would point out http://stackoverflow.com/a/27838890/2286132 by atish shimpi. @TheLostMind: you are perfectly right, it just happened to be so that the cases I was dealing with where peek, poll and clear, so they ended up in the example!

Comment: The problem will be when one thread calls `add()` and you are calling `clear()` in another thread. There will certainly be inconsistency. Better use `Collections.synchronizedList()`

Comment: @TheLostMind (and whoever feels able to answer ^^): isn't that just why I put the synchronized(list){} block around add, clear, poll and so on, so I can workwith a non.synchronized list? I am not sure if you are clarifying the scope of my question, or I am missing something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to make synchronization as specific as possible instead of marking the whole method with the keyword. The more refined your synchronization is the better your code will perform. Should suggest the latter code that you have shown and synchronize on the same lock when working with the list among threads.

As in your case if you do as below as you have shown it should be okay:

```
synchronized(list){
    // do something with your list
    // synchronizing on the same lock makes sure other threads have to wait for this lock
    // to be released. In your case you are using the list object as the lock.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass your list to the `public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list)` method in the `java.util.Collections` class to create a thread-safe list.

Comment: Will need to see if the List without peek/poll will work in my environment, but this little snippet sure is useful, never saw it before :)

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Vector`  is  thread-safely, all methods in this class are `synchronized`

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you are going to implement some kind of Producer/Consumer pattern, use existing tools - class implementing ["Blocking Queue"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) should suit your needs